# Is it a bad idea to sub-class java.io.File?

Tags: java, truezip

I am having a debate with another developer who dislikes my idea of sub-classing `java.io.File` for our custom needs (such as, for example, having an `AWSFile`, or `GoogleCloudStorageFile`, (for the sake of argument), where we would need to override some of the methods like `listFiles()`, `getAbsoluteFile`, etc.). When is it okay to sub-class `java.io.File`?

Why is there, for example, no generic interface for this, which `java.io.File` could be implementing, so that it would be more generic? Was this done so on purpose?

I would like to understand whether, or not my approach is indeed good, or bad, as I've seen it in other API-s before (if I recall correctly, I'd seen the same approach in `TrueZip` a while ago).

The purpose of this question is not to start a flame war, or anything, but to get an examples of how to implement different types of `File` entities (`AWSFile`, `JDBCFile`, etc.) and potentially get a meaningful list of pros and cons.

Comment: The first line of the class's javadoc states: ``An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.`` - that sounds like the ideal class to subclass for your needs. My main concern is that there's a load of methods that probably won't be applicable for something like a cloud file and none of the methods should be inherited. The cleaner approach would be to implement a ``File`` interface, which does not exist in java. So... keep debating :D

Comment: I would say your approach is good..

Comment: I see no need to subclass.  You can implement those methods if you wish without subclassing.  Inheritance means IS-A; that is not the case here.

Comment: What is the arguments agains this approach? For me it sounds good.

Comment: @duffymo Isn't `AWSFile` or `GoogleCloudStorageFile` a `File`?

Comment: What would be the point of subclassing `File` to represent a non-local file? It can't be used with any Java `File` API like `FileReader` or `FileOutputStream`. If you want to support non-local "files" and use them like files, you should instead implement your own [`FileSystemProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html) (Java 7+).

Comment: IS-A holds only if you can satisfy the Liskov Substitution principle: Can you use your subclass in every situation where a File is correct?  That means every method in the API, not one or two that you want to cherry pick.

Comment: Why not base your API on the `java.nio.file` API, instead of the old `java.io.File` etc.? See, for example, class [`java.nio.file.FileSystems`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html) to learn what you need to do to provide your own `FileSystem` implementation.

Comment: You should only subclass if any class which currently takes a File as argument, would work with an AWSFile. Would they? What would mkdir() do? Btw: I think you want to implement InputStream and OutputStream instead.

Comment: This is a interesting question, but it's too open for arguments and discussion, so it must be closed according to the rules. Here's my two cents: I join @duffymo's comment.

Comment: I think that sub-classing is very bad idea in this case, and there are many reasons why it is bad:

 1. If `Java SDK` developers supposed that somebody need to totally override or extend some entities then they make Interfaces or Abstract classes, like they do with `InputStream` and `OutputStream` for example.
 2. You can't override some final or hidden members like `java.io.File.fs` which is used in other `Java SDK` components and can cause them to be confused;
 3. You can have a lot of problems in case of migration from one Java version to another.

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference would be that you make an interface `RemoteFile` and you implement there the methods you need for the remote files.

In it I would suggest you put all the method types you will need for remote getting and setting file.

```
public interface RemoteFile {
    public File getLocalFile();
    public String getRemotePath();
    public boolean isDirectory();
    public List<RemoteFile> listFiles();
    ... etc...
}
```

Comment: Why would you this? What are the pros/cons? Why should this be considered a better approach? The OP seems to be  searching for an argumented ansawer.

Answer (score -1):

Subclasses will be tightly coupled to superclasses, your code would be weak. You must try delegation before inheritance if possible.

```
public class YourFileWrapper {

private File yourFile;


public File getYourFile() {
    return yourFile;
} 
//rest of your code
```

Comment: I don't understand what's "weak" about inheritance. Therefore, I don't see why one should prefer delegation over inheritance.

Comment: As i already explained, "Subclasses will be tightly coupled to superclasses"

Comment: Yes, that's what inheritance means. What's the bad thing about that? And if it's bad, why is there inheritance everywhere in every project in every oop language language?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/2or9oz/what_are_the_benefits_and_drawbacks_of_a_tightly/

Comment: That is in no way a reason to promote delegation instead of inheritance. But if you want to avoid inheritance in your projects, do so. As long as nobody else ever has to work on them.